# Is there any way in elasticsearch to redirect specific search results to Context Suggester?

Tags: elasticsearch, django-rest-framework

I'm aware what says elasticsearch documentation about ***Conetxt Suggesters*** and how mutilple context categories are resolved in suggestions.

> If multiple categories or category contexts are set on the query they are merged as a disjunction. This means that suggestions match if they contain at least one of the provided context values.

I'm looking rather for something to resemble conjunction between ***context*** ***categories***.
I know for know it's rather impossible to change this behaviour.

My request looks like this

```
GET /biz_index/_search
{
  "suggest": {
    "suggest_biz": {
      "text": "my text", 
      "completion": {
        "field": "suggest_biz", 
        "contexts": { 
          "is_paid": [
            {"context": true}, 
            {"context": false, "boost": 2}
          ], 
          "is_hidden": True, 
          "location": {"lat": 40.6331, "lon": -89.3985}
        }, 
        "size": 10, 
        "fuzzy": {
          "fuzziness": 1, 
          "min_length": 3, 
          "prefix_length": 3
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if its possible to reach something like:  **is_hidden** AND (**is_paid** OR **location**).

Maybe through fetching all biz with flag **is_hidden** and redirecting results to **suggester**.

Thank you for any help.